# ReactJS: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, swiftype

I am working on a search engine using the swiftype reackJS demo app as a starting point. It's using the search-ui npm.

I get: Cannot read property 'raw' of undefined

```
   export default ({ result }) => (
        <img
          id="offre_logo_3"
          alt=""
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            zIndex: 1002,
            display: "block",
            top: "88px",
            margin: "0 auto",
            height: "30px",
            width: "30px"
          }}
          src={"https://www.cliiic.com/images/" + result.icone.raw}
        />
   );
```

result.icone.raw is properly set up from what I understand in the App.js file like this:

```
result_fields: {
  id: { raw: {} },
  couleur: { raw: {} },
  icone: { raw: {} },
  notice: { raw: {} },
  short_title: {
    snippet: {
      size: 50,
      fallback: true
    }
  },
  name: {
    snippet: {
      size: 50,
      fallback: true
    }
  },
  city: { raw: {} },
  region: { raw: {} },
  zip: { raw: {} },
  type: { raw: {} },
  accepted_clic: { raw: {} },
  alltxt: { raw: {} },
  price: { raw: {} },
  quantity: { raw: {} },
  start_date: { raw: {} },
  end_date: { raw: {} },
  newmembersonly: { raw: {} },
  main_category: { raw: {} },
  secondary_category: { raw: {} }
}
```

Testing app posted here https://5kyd5.csb.app/offre.php?q=test&size=n_20_n
(Loads a blank page because of the error. Open up console to see whats happening)

Source code can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/video-games-tutorial-with-images-5kyd5

I can see the icone col in the swiftype schema table and it's populated as expected.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I posted the result object in the console and everything seems ok in the way I am trying to access the object value.

This is a link to the JSON object returned by the API
https://jsonblob.com/d081e6ed-186c-11ea-a766-135bd1c509b2

[image]

=================
EDIT:

I think I may have found the problem ... By looking at the JSON the API returns, I noticed the icone var is not in the first result!

https://jsonblob.com/d081e6ed-186c-11ea-a766-135bd1c509b2

So that means the product was proberbly deleted and not sync with the elastic search system. Is there a way to avoid a blanc page if the var is none existing?

Comment: Have you tried logging `result` to see what properties it has?

Comment: That's a good suggestion. How would I do that in react?

Comment: `console.log(result)` at point in the code where `result` is defined.

Comment: Done please see the testing app

Comment: I posted a link to the source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link for a working sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/video-games-tutorial-with-images-6zh7i

If you want everything to be sync you can create const fields before returning which will be assigned an empty object if those keys are `undefined`

e.g `const {icone} = result || {}`

You ca do this for all keys if you want.

Comment: I posted result in console and everything looks ok. It's the right var to use.

Comment: Yes I verified it through dev tools as well

Comment: Can you tell me if it works if you remove it from src completely?

Comment: Yes it works If i remove it. My other vars seems to print fine with out any errors. (name, short_title, id, price) ect ... Only icone and couleur seems to be the problem. (The last 2 i recently added to swiftype)

Comment: Check out my solution, it works perfectly even after search.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `result_fields` object but calling `result` object. Try renaming your object to be the same and see if you continue to experience issues!

Edit: It seems you're calling some script/api/carrier-pigeon to populate the `result` object. However, when you call the element you're exporting, that object may not exist yet. Try modifying your export to the following and you should see what I'm talking about:

```
export default ({ result }) => {
console.log('And the results are in!', result);
return (
        <img
          id="offre_logo_3"
          alt=""
          style={{
            position: "relative",
            zIndex: 1002,
            display: "block",
            top: "88px",
            margin: "0 auto",
            height: "30px",
            width: "30px"
          }}
          src={"https://www.cliiic.com/images/" + result.icone.raw}
        />
   )};
```

Comment: Actualy using result works great ... I used a few values already to show ID, Price and Name. the header of the loop looks like this ```export default ({ result }) => (```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about as that's not part of any of the excerpts in your post. All I can tell you is that you're saying that the value is being initially set by your App.js using the object `result_fields: {...}` but your img element is calling for the `result` object.

Comment: I posted result in console and everything looks ok. It's the right var to use.

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully be more clear as to what I believe the issue is.

Comment: I did what you asked and see the object correctly in the dev tool. Please open the testing app and see for your self. Thx for the help btw!

Comment: I don't understand why, but I forked your codesandbox and it works perfectly in my fork with absolutely no changes.... https://codesandbox.io/s/video-games-tutorial-with-images-lgesj

Comment: It's not working. Type something in the search bar that has results like "test" and you will have the same error.